# increase pageSize of Generic Test Data results in sonarqube 6.2

Tags: sonarqube

I have imported test results according to https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Generic+Test+Data into SonarQube 6.2.

I can look at the detailed test results in sonar by navigating to the test file and then by clicking menu "Show Measures". The opened page then shows me the correct total number of tests 293 of which 31 failed. The test result details section however only shows 100 test results.

This page seems to get its data through a request like: http://localhost:9000/api/tests/list?testFileId=AVpC5Jod-2ky3xCh908m
with a result of:

```
{
  paging: {
    pageIndex: 1,
    pageSize: 100,
    total: 293
  },
  tests: [
    {
      id: "AVpDK1X_-2ky3xCh91QQ",
      name: "GuiButton:Type Checks->disabledBackgroundColor",
      fileId: "AVpC5Jod-2ky3xCh908m",
      fileKey: "org.sonarqube:Scripting-Tests-Publishing:dummytests/ScriptingEngine.Objects.GuiButtonTest.js",
      fileName: "dummytests/ScriptingEngine.Objects.GuiButtonTest.js",
      status: "OK",
      durationInMs: 8
...
}
```

From this I gather that the page size is set to 100 in the backend. Is there a way to increase it so that I can see all test results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can certainly call the web service with a larger page size parameter value, but you cannot change the page size requested by the UI